# How do I find the duration of an event for a Pandas time series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I identify positive and negative periods in the below time series in the ['sign'] column. How can I get each duration of 1 and -1 and then count the number of periods with 1 and -1?

So if I have five consecutive '1' and then three consecutive '-1' followed by two '1' in the ['sign'] column, the answer is duration: 5 days, 3 days and 2 days. Then counting. '1': 2 and '-1': 1.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

end = dt.datetime(2016, 12, 31)
start = dt.date(end.year-15, end.month, end.day)

aapl = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close']
aapl = pd.DataFrame(aapl)
aapl['ema'] = aapl.ewm(200).mean()
aapl['diff'] = (aapl['Adj Close'] / aapl['ema']) - 1
aapl['sign'] = np.sign(aapl['diff'])
```

**UPDATE:** 
I realised that would need separate counts of periods where sign = '1' and sign = '-1' when it comes to durations. This is to do descriptive statistics on '1' and '-1' periods.

Pandas version: 0.19.2

Comment: For the UPDATE part, could you add a sample and expected o/p?

Comment: In [1]: duration_up_count(a)
Out[2]: (array([5, 2])) using your array, and equivalent for down. Then skip the accumulated counting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`diff()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) and a subsequent [`cumsum()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to get the differences in the Series, and groupby accordingly.

```
aapl.groupby((aapl.sign.diff() != 0).cumsum()).size()
```

As for getting the counts of each sign group, there may be a more clever way to do this but you could re-use the same `diff` result to index your original `sign` Series after removing duplicates.

```
aapl.sign.iloc[(aapl.sign.diff() != 0).cumsum().drop_duplicates().index]
               .value_counts().to_dict()
```

Putting this nicely in a function may look like

```
def durs(df):
    diffs = (df.sign.diff() != 0).cumsum()
    cnts = df.sign.iloc[diffs.drop_duplicates().index].value_counts().to_dict()
    days = df.groupby(diffs).size()
    return days, cnts
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df
   sign
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5    -1
6    -1
7    -1
8     1
9     1

>>> days, cnts = durs(df)

>>> days
sign
1    5
2    3
3    2
dtype: int64

>>> cnts
{-1: 1, 1: 2}
```

---

***Update***

For your added request in the comments of *only* counting the 1-periods and subsequently getting an output of `[5, 2]`, you could use something like this, getting the indices of the 1's and then grouping by consecutives.

```
>>> data = np.where(df.sign == 1)[0]

>>> np.diff(np.r_[0, np.where(np.diff(data) != 1)[0]+1, data.size])
array([5, 2])
```

<sub>Mind you, I am not a NumPy expert so no guarantees about performance here.</sub>

Comment: When running your function on the dataframe from my question, I get the following error message on the following code: cnts = df.sign.iloc[diffs.drop_duplicates().index].value_counts().to_dict()  Error message: TypeError: invalid type promotion

Comment: @cJc which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I realised that would need separate counts of periods where sign = '1' and sign = '-1' when it comes to durations. This is to do descriptive statistics on '1' and '-1' periods.

Comment: Pandas version 0.19.2

Comment: If I could get this: aapl.groupby((aapl.sign.diff() != 0).cumsum()).size()  to return the calculation for only ['sign'] = 1, then I should be able to make this work as I want.

Comment: @cJc I' m not really sure what you mean - could you please add an exampl with input and output to your question?

Comment: As per my update, if I find the no. of days per sequence where ['sign'] = 1. From your Demo above, the output would now be: 5, 2.. Skipping the '-1'.

Comment: Works like a charm! Tnx for your efforts:)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach for an array -

```
def duration_count(a):
    idx = np.r_[[0],np.flatnonzero(a[1:] != a[:-1])+1,a.size]
    duration = np.diff(idx)
    count = {a[0]:(duration.size+1)//2, -a[0]:duration.size//2}
    return duration, count
```

Sample runs -

```
In [43]: a = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1])

In [44]: duration_count(a)
Out[44]: (array([5, 3, 2]), {-1: 1, 1: 2})

In [45]: a = np.array([-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1])

In [46]: duration_count(a)
Out[46]: (array([2, 5, 3, 2, 4]), {-1: 3, 1: 2})
```

Comment: Please see updated question: I realised that would need separate counts of periods where sign = '1' and sign = '-1' when it comes to durations. This is to do descriptive statistics on '1' and '-1' periods.